# Change screen lock method

Tags: android, lockscreen

Is there a way to programmatically change the phones screen lock method? For example, changing it to display a pattern, a pin, swipe unlock or none at all.

For example, think of a widget that lets the user toggle between swipe to unlock and pattern lock.

Cyanogenmod has something like this in their profiles, using [PROFILE_SERVICE](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/jellybean/src/com/android/settings/profiles/ProfileConfig.java#L109) but that does not seem to be in the public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. Through `DevicePolicyManager`, you can specify some minimum quality characteristics for a password, and force the user to reset their password to meet those characteristics. However:

- The user can always choose something stronger than what you require
- This requires that the user configure your app as a device admin
- This requires additional permissions
- The user is always involved in the password-reset process

Comment: What you are looking for is not possible.